# Printing only part of next line after matching a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to print next sentence after match
My file content like this:

```
SSID:CoreFragment
Passphrase:WiFi1234
SSID:CoreFragment_5G
Passphrase:WiFi1234
SSID:Aleph_inCar
Passphrase:1234567890
```

As per my search,e.g. If I found `WIFI-3(SSID)` than, I want to print `1234ABCD`. I used this command to search SSID:

```
grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' file_name
```

After this search I want to print Passphrase of that particular match.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04

```
ssid=$(grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' list_wifi.txt)
for ssid in $(sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f2)
do
    if [ $ssid == $ssid_name ]; then
       echo "SSID found...";
    fi
done
```

I want to print next line after match.

Comment: since you haven't used code tags so your samples are not cleared, please add code tags to them.

Comment: this is code sample:                                                                                                                     ssid=$(grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' list_wifi.txt)
for ssid in $(sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f2)
do
    if [ $ssid == $ssid_name ]; then
       echo "SSID found...";
    fi
done

After echo "SSID found..."; this statement i want to print Passphrase

Comment: ssid=$(grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' list_wifi.txt)
for ssid in $(sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f2)
do
    if [ $ssid == $ssid_name ]; then
       echo "SSID found...";
       password=$(awk '/$ssid/{flag=1;next} flag{sub(/.*:/,"");print $0;flag=""}' list_wifi.txt)
       echo " $password";
   fi
done                                                                                                                            In this I got just blank line

Comment: @yashshah: How did you even run my command? You are testing it incorrectly. My answer solves the exact problem you have

Comment: No... i do exactly as per your suggested command but i want to store that value in variable ... Normally it works but when I store it into value it doesn't works....

Comment: @yashshah: to store it in  a variable do `pass=$(sed -n '/\<'"$ssid"'\>/{n; s/.*://p;}' file
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F: -v s="$ssid" '$0=="SSID:"s{c=NR+1} c==NR{print $2; exit}' file

1234ABCD
```

will only print the value if it's on the next line.

Comment: While I store this command in variable it won't print anything

Comment: my ssid is not fixed everytime,so how to print for other ssid, i tried to use $ssid but it not works

Comment: this will do the search for given value in variable `$ssid`.

Comment: but it not works for me, I'm getting blank line in output

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '/WIFI-3/{getline;print $2; exit}' file

1234ABCD
```

Comment: I would just put an extra `exit` after the print statement. Just in case his password file is several GB big ;-)

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for the hint.

Comment: and fingers crossed the getline doesn't fail or you'll quietly end up with part of the WIFI-3 line in your output and think it succeeded. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to call getline safely (but its best just avoided in this case).

Comment: If "WIFI-3" appears as a passphrase, this will print the next SSID value.

Answer (score 1):

Robustly (wont fail due to partial matches, etc.) and idiomatically:

```
$ awk -F':' 'f{print $2; exit} ($1=="SSID") && ($2=="WIFI-3"){f=1}' file
1234ABCD
```

Comment: for generic way, how it will help me?

Comment: my ssid may be change, whill i tried to use $ssid in this command it doesn't display result

Comment: Pass it in as a variable `awk -v ssid="$ssid" '... ($1==ssid) ...'`

Answer (score 0):

Since code tags have changed the look of samples so adding this now.

```
var=$(awk '/SSID:[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+/{flag=1;next} flag{sub(/.*:/,"");value=$0;flag=""} END{print value}' Input_file)
echo "$var"
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/Passphrase/ && match($0,/WIFI-3 Passphrase:[0-9a-zA-Z]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*:/,"",val);print val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @yashshah, 1st one is not working too, it worked for me, check once?

Comment: Yes,it might be works but I want to print Passphrase of match. WIFI-3 is just example I need this in more generic way

Comment: I want to print only one Passphrase but as per your answer I'm getting all

Comment: @yashshah, please check first one now?

Comment: It only print in command-line but when I store in variable it not works....

Comment: @yashshah, please check my first one now?

Comment: I tried your new asnwer but in that it prints all passphrase I want to print next line passphrase only

Comment: @yashshah, please try now 1st one once?

Comment: As per your updated answer it always print last passphrase

Comment: @yashshah, right I thought that's what you need, no?

Comment: No.. we have to print next passphrase of matched SSID which means if my SSID  is CoreFragment than it should print WiFi1234 like that

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
ssid="WIFI-3"
passphrase=$(grep -A 1 "^SSID:$ssid" file_name | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f2)
echo "$passphrase"
```

which yields:

```
1234ABCD
```

Comment: Can we store this into variable? I have to use it further in shell script

Comment: Sure. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ export ssid="WIFI-3"
$ perl -0777 -lne ' /SSID:$ENV{ssid}\s*Passphrase:(\S+)/ and print $1 ' yash.txt
1234ABCD
$ export ssid="Aleph_inCar"
$ perl -0777 -lne ' /SSID:$ENV{ssid}\s*Passphrase:(\S+)/ and print $1 ' yash.txt
1234567890
$

$ cat yash.txt
SSID:CoreFragment
Passphrase:WiFi1234
SSID:CoreFragment_5G
Passphrase:WiFi1234
SSID:Aleph_inCar
Passphrase:1234567890
SSID:WIFI-1
Passphrase:1234ABCD
SSID:WIFI-2
Passphrase:123456789
SSID:WIFI-3
Passphrase:1234ABCD
```

You can capture it in variables as

```
$ passphrase=$(perl -0777 -lne ' /SSID:$ENV{ssid}\s*Passphrase:(\S+)/ and print $1 ' yash.txt)
$ echo $passphrase
1234567890
$
```

Comment: I want this in shell script

Comment: yes.. you can call perl inside shell script also.. what I posted is a one-liner.. it will work

Comment: I just updated the answer with an example.. pls check

Comment: it's not printing anything

Comment: you have to ````export ssid="WIFI-3"```` not just ````ssid="WIFI-3"````

Comment: it works.. could you pls check the case sensitivity between your input and what I have in my answer?

Comment: I'm getting blank line in output

Comment: were you able to replicate my answer?.. pls also share the input where you get blank.. you can update that in the question